# undirected_dfs & make_predecessor_recorder : compilation error

Tags: c++, boost-graph, visitor-pattern

My  goal is to detect cycles in an undirected graph.

I try to adapt the djiskra shortest path with predecessor_recorder and predecessor map to the undirected_dfs.

I use the code available here :http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/quick_tour.html
Cut & paste of  :

Part 1:

```
template <class PredecessorMap>
  class record_predecessors : public dijkstra_visitor<>
  {
  public:
    record_predecessors(PredecessorMap p)
      : m_predecessor(p) { }

    template <class Edge, class Graph>
    void edge_relaxed(Edge e, Graph& g) {
      // set the parent of the target(e) to source(e)
      put(m_predecessor, target(e, g), source(e, g));
    }
  protected:
    PredecessorMap m_predecessor;
  };
```

Part 2:

```
template <class PredecessorMap>
  record_predecessors<PredecessorMap>
  make_predecessor_recorder(PredecessorMap p) {
    return record_predecessors<PredecessorMap>(p);
  }
```

the call to undirected_dfs is:

```
boost::undirected_dfs(g, boost::make_dfs_visitor(make_predecessor_recorder(&p[0])), vertex_color_map, edge_color_map);
```

The compilation error on Visual studio is :

```
visitors.hpp(124): error : class "record_predecessors<Vertex={size_t={unsigned __int64}} *>" has no member "event_filter"
```

Do you have an idea on how to solve this issue ?

Thank you

Here is the code

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/undirected_dfs.hpp>
#include<boost/graph/properties.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/named_function_params.hpp>            //for named parameter http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/bgl_named_params.html
#include <boost/cstdlib.hpp>                                                    // for exit_success;
//#include <boost/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/visitors.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>                                //pring_graph
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>                  //dijkstra_visitor


//template du graph http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html
typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS,                        //OutEdgeList
    boost::vecS,                        //VertexList
    boost::undirectedS          //Directednes
//  boost::no_property,         //VertexProperties
//  boost::no_property,         //EdgeProperties
//  boost::no_property,         //GraphProperties
//  boost::listS                        //EdgeList
> Graph;

typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;


template <class PredecessorMap>
class record_predecessors : public boost::dijkstra_visitor<>
{
public:
    record_predecessors(PredecessorMap p)
        : m_predecessor(p) { }

    template <class Edge, class Graph>
    void tree_edge(Edge e, Graph& g) {
        // set the parent of the target(e) to source(e)
        put(m_predecessor, target(e, g), source(e, g));
    };
protected:
    PredecessorMap m_predecessor;
};

template <class PredecessorMap>
record_predecessors<PredecessorMap>
make_predecessor_recorder(PredecessorMap p) {
    return record_predecessors<PredecessorMap>(p);
}

template <typename event_type>
struct test_visitor : public boost::default_bfs_visitor {
    using event_filter = event_type;

    void operator()(Vertex, Graph const&) const {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
    void tree_edge{};
    void back_edge{};
    void examine_edge{};
    void discover_vertex{};
    void finish_vertex{};
    void initialize_vertex{};
    void tree_vertex{};
    void start_vertex{};

    void forwared_or_cross_edge{};

};

struct detect_loops : public boost::dfs_visitor<>
{
    //source:https://github.com/orocos-toolchain/utilmm/blob/master/test/test_undirected_graph.cc
    using colormap = std::map<Graph::vertex_descriptor, boost::default_color_type>;
    colormap vertex_coloring;

    //source:https://github.com/orocos-toolchain/utilmm/blob/master/test/test_undirected_graph.cc
    using edgeColorMap = std::map<Graph::edge_descriptor, boost::default_color_type>;
    edgeColorMap  edge_coloring;

    template <class Edge, class Graph>
    void tree_edge(Edge e, const Graph& g) {
        boost::record_predecessors()
            std::cout << "tree_edge: " << boost::source(e, g) << " --> " << boost::target(e, g) << std::endl;
        std::cout << " tree_edge ";
    }

    template <class Edge, class Graph>
    void back_edge(Edge e, const Graph& g) {
        std::cout << "back_edge: " << boost::source(e, g) << " --> " << boost::target(e, g) << std::endl;
    }
};


//---------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------
Graph make(Graph &g)
{
    boost::add_vertex(g);
    boost::add_vertex(g);
    boost::add_vertex(g);
    boost::add_vertex(g);
    boost::add_vertex(g);
    boost::add_edge(0, 1, g);
    boost::add_edge(0, 2, g);
    boost::add_edge(1, 0, g);
    boost::add_edge(2, 4, g);
    boost::add_edge(4, 3, g);
    boost::add_edge(3, 1, g);
    return g;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    Graph g;
    detect_loops vis;

    make(g);

    typedef std::map<boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor, boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor> EdgeMap;
    typedef boost::associative_property_map<EdgeMap> PredecessorMap;
    typedef boost::edge_predecessor_recorder<PredecessorMap, boost::on_tree_edge> PredecessorVisitor;

    std::vector< int > predecessorMap(boost::num_vertices(g));


    typedef boost::associative_property_map<  std::map<Graph::edge_descriptor, boost::default_color_type>   >EdgeColorMap;
    EdgeColorMap edge_color_map;

    typedef boost::associative_property_map<  std::map<Graph::vertex_descriptor, boost::default_color_type>   >VertexColorMap;
    VertexColorMap vertex_color_map;

    //source 1: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/doc/undirected_dfs.html
    //source 2: https://github.com/orocos-toolchain/utilmm/blob/master/test/test_undirected_graph.cc
    // named parameter version:  template <typename Graph, typename P, typename T, typename R>
    //boost::undirected_dfs(g, vis, vertex_color_map, edge_color_map);

    std::vector<Vertex> p(boost::num_vertices(g), boost::graph_traits<Graph>::null_vertex()); //the predecessor array

    // The source vertex
    Graph::vertex_descriptor s = *(boost::vertices(g).first);
    p[s] = s;
    std::cout << "num vertices= " << boost::num_vertices(g) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "num vertices= " <<  boost::num_vertices(g), boost::graph_traits<Graph>::null_vertex();

    boost::print_graph(g);

    //undirected_dfs(const Graph& g, DFSVisitor vis,VertexColorMap vertex_color, EdgeColorMap edge_color)
/*
boost::undirected_dfs(      g,
                                            //boost::visitor( boost::make_dfs_visitor(boost::record_predecessors(p.begin() , boost::on_tree_edge )) ),
                                            boost::make_dfs_visitor( make_predecessor_recorder( &p[0] ) ),
                                            vertex_color_map,
                                            edge_color_map);
*/

    boost::undirected_dfs(  g,
                                        boost::visitor( boost::make_dfs_visitor( std::make_pair( make_predecessor_recorder(&p[0]), test_visitor<boost::on_discover_vertex>() ) ) ),
                                        vertex_color_map, edge_color_map);
    /*
    /// Declare predecessor map
    typedef std::vector <Vertex> predecessors_t;
    typedef boost::iterator_property_map <typename predecessors_t::iterator, IndexMap> predecessor_map_t;
    predecessors_t predecessors(boost::num_vertices(g), boost::graph_traits<Graph>::null_vertex();;
    predecessor_map_t predecessor_map(predecessors.begin(), index_map);

    boost::depth_first_visit(g, s, boost::make_dfs_visitor(boost::record_predecessors(predecessor_map, boost::on_tree_edge())), vertex_color_map);
    */
    return boost::exit_success;
}
```

Comment: I've spent 20 minutes trying to piece together what you **MIGHT** mean you got. Just post the SSCCE, will you?

Comment: I add the code with compilation errors.  My goal was to used undirected_dfs with record_processor and record map.

Comment: Thanks. Though it made me go "huh" there's not a lot we can do from code that should not compile for language reasons. Nothing closely related to the error you're having. Why not go back to a sample of `undirected_dfs` (and oh it seems you misspelled dfs as bfs at least once)

Comment: you are right. Now i am using http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/example/undirected_dfs.cpp ; However,  undirected_dfs discover basic cycles. Now, I have to merge cycles with common edge. But that will be a new stackoverflow thread. Thank you for all.